# ASP MVC javascript lazy loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

in view, i have at the bottom many javascript and jquery code, and i dont like it, so im placing all scripts into one ascx file, and make partial rendering like:

```
<!--<%Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Home/StationLogics.ascx"); %>-->
```

of this ascx file with scripts. So, is there any better way?

cant place it to master page, cause not always i need this scripts, if user get some privilage, he can use some scripts, if not - others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add your common JavaScript files in the `head` element of a [Master page](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/106/master-pages/), and then let your pages reference that master page using the `<%@ Page %>` directive, for example:

```
<%@ Page MasterPageFile="/Views/Shared/Site.Master" %>
```

Now, all you have to do is update the scripts in your master page, and pages referencing that master page will have the scripts as well.

However, if your scripts are too specific to include in the master page, then your solution is probably fine.

Answer (score 1):

it mat not be what u intended to know but i think that u can place all ur javascript and jquery code in a js file like in yourjavascript.js file and place a reference of js file in your view or the master page page file that the view is inheriting e.g.

```
<script src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/scripts/yourjavascript.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```